# Autolayout position reset

Tags: ios, iphone, layout, autolayout, xib

I have a View and i have a an image view inside it and a another UiView and one or two more view in side the top level view. The problem is when i run my app in different screens iphone the image view resizes and i want the other view to change the  their position to a little bit down. But only image view gets more space, but i don't want the other view to get more space but i want them to change their position.

[image]

Here i want the white view the Placeholder text and the the small picture view to change their position and go a bit down when the app runs on big screen iphone. Th rounded image view above the Mybutton gets more space when the screen resizes which is okay but the white view and other view remain at their same place. Just to add more information all these view are siblings of each other and i have fixed the the width and height of the white view, picture view and the placeholder text label

Any guidance please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to start with the "movable" element and then add every "fixed" element.

I think you have to work with `Center Y Alignment Contraint` even if you have to create new view for it. The beginning could be :

[image]